# Resetting multiple ng-options inputs to default value together

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html

I have a search which filters products stored as JSON data based on multiple select inputs which store their value as scope variables (3 outputted using ng-options, 1 hardcoded).

I have a 'Clear Filters' button which resets the variables stored for the filters, but when I try to reset the inputs to their default values at the same time only some reset. If only one filter has been selected it will always reset.

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <select ng-options="loc as loc.name for loc in yachtLocations | filter:{parent:0}:true"  class="form-control" ng-model="nameRegion" ng-change="updateRegionValues(nameRegion, 'yachts')">
        <option value="">Select Region</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
        <select ng-options="loc as loc.name for loc in yachtLocations | filter:filterCountries"  class="form-control"  ng-model="nameCountry" ng-change="updateCountryValues(nameCountry, 'yachts')">
            <option value="">Select Country</option>
        </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <select ng-options="loc as loc.name for loc in yachtLocations | filter:filterDest"  class="form-control"  ng-model="namePort" ng-change="updateDestValues(namePort, 'yachts')">
        <option value="">Select Port</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control" ng-model="valueType" ng-change="updateTypeValues(valueType, 'yachts')">
        <option value="">Vessel Type</option>
        <option value="20">Motor</option>
        <option value="19">Sail</option>
    </select>
</div>

<a class="clearFilters" ng-show="emptyFilters()" ng-click="resetValues()">Clear Filters</a>
```

Relevant JS:

```
totApp.controller('mainController',['$scope', '$filter', function ($scope, $filter){
$scope.yachts = yachts;
$scope.superyachts = superyachts;
$scope.motorboats = motorboats;
$scope.yachtLocations = yachtLocations;
$scope.superYachtTenderLocations = superYachtTenderLocations;
$scope.motorBoatLocations = motorBoatLocations;
$scope.type = null;

$scope.loc = {
    region : { name : '', id : null },
    country : { name : '', id : null, children : 0 },
    dest : { name : '', id : null }
}

$scope.updateRegionValues = function($value, $type) {

    if ($value == null) {
        $scope.loc.region.name = '';
        $scope.loc.region.id = null;
        $scope.loc.country.name = '';
        $scope.loc.country.id = null;
        $scope.loc.country.children = 0;
        $scope.loc.dest.name = '';
        $scope.loc.dest.id = null;
    } 
    else {
        var termID = $value.term_id;
        $scope.changeRegion(termID, $type);
        $scope.showAllItems($type);
    }       
}


$scope.updateCountryValues = function($value, $type) {
    if ($value == null) {
        $scope.loc.country.name = '';
        $scope.loc.country.id = null;
        $scope.loc.country.children = 0;
        $scope.loc.dest.name = '';
        $scope.loc.dest.id = null;
    } 
    else {
        var termID = $value.term_id;
        var children = $value.children
        $scope.changeCountry(termID, children, $type);
        $scope.showAllItems($type);
    }       
}

$scope.updateDestValues = function($value, $type) {
    if ($value == null) {
        $scope.loc.dest.name = '';
        $scope.loc.dest.id = null;
    } 
    else {
        var termID = $value.term_id;
        $scope.changeDest(termID, $type);
        $scope.showAllItems($type);
    }       
}

$scope.updateTypeValues = function($value, $boat) {
    if ($value == null) {
        $scope.type = null;
    }
    else {
        $scope.updateType(parseInt($value));
        $scope.showAllItems($boat);
    }   
}

$scope.resetValues = function() {
    $scope.pagesShown = 1;
    $scope.loc.region.name = '';
    $scope.loc.region.id = null;
    $scope.loc.country.name = '';
    $scope.loc.country.id = null;
    $scope.loc.country.children = 0;
    $scope.loc.dest.name = '';
    $scope.loc.dest.id = null;
    $scope.type = null;
}

$scope.updateType = function($value) {
    $scope.type = $value;
}

//Same function for scope.loc.country and scope.loc.dest
//code using $type edited out
$scope.changeRegion = function( id, $type ){
    $scope.loc.region.id = id;
    }
}
```

I've tried using

```
<option ng-selected="this.loc.dest.id == null" value="">Select Port</option>
```

(the same for each relevant scope variable on each option)
As well as

```
$('.form-control').val("");
```

and

```
$('.form-control').prop("selectedIndex", 0);
```

at the bottom of the $scope.resetValues function. All of these solutions produce the same result - one or two `<select>`s will be reset unless only one has been changed.

----------EDIT----------

forgot to include the filters.

```
$scope.filterCountries = function($country) {
    if ($scope.loc.region.id != null) {
        return $country.parent == $scope.loc.region.id;
    }
    else {
        var parents = new Array();
        var location;


            location = $scope.yachtLocations;


        angular.forEach(location, function(location){
            if (location.parent == 0) {
                parents.push(location.term_id);
            }
        });

        return parents.includes($country.parent);
    }
}

$scope.filterDest = function($dest) {

    if($scope.loc.country.id != null) {
        return $dest.parent == $scope.loc.country.id;
    }

    else {
        var parents = new Array();
        var moreparents = new Array();
        var location;

        location = $scope.yachtLocations;

        angular.forEach(location, function(location){
            if (location.parent == 0) {
                parents.push(location.term_id);
            }
        });

        angular.forEach(location, function(location){
            if (parents.includes(location.parent)) {
                moreparents.push(location.term_id);
            }
        });

        return moreparents.includes($dest.parent);

    }
}
```

Comment: That would be great if you provided some jsfiddle link.

Comment: I think that the reason is that you are resetting the wrong variables (not you have mapped on).

Comment: @MaKCbIMKo Definitely not, if I was resetting the wrong variables the search itself wouldn't work properly, which it does.

Comment: @MaKCbIMKo I'll work on getting a fiddle up for it though to try to illustrate it better

Answer (score 0):

What you want to reset are the `ng-model`-values. If you change your code to this it should work:

```
$scope.resetValues = function() {
    $scope.nameRegion = ''; //Default value here
    $scope.nameCountry = '';//Default value here
    $scope.namePort = '';//Default value here
    $scope.valueType = '';//Default value here
}
```

Comment: I'd like to keep the existing array format if possible, could I reformat it to something along these lines:

ng-model="loc.nameRegion"

$scope.loc = {
nameRegion : { name : '', id : null } }

Comment: @briainod heading home now, I'll update my answer later today.